# How can I get a TabPage from a TabControl based on a Point?

Tags: .net, winforms, mouse, tabcontrol, tabpage

Surely this has *got* to be easy; I'm just not having any luck with it.

How would I get the `TabPage` of a given `TabControl` whose tab contains a given `Point`? For example, if I'm handling the `MouseUp` event and I want to know which tab the mouse was over when it was released.

I tried `GetChildAtPoint`, but that seems to always return the first tab (unless I'm using it wrong).

Comment: You mean that you want the page which its header hovered, right?

Comment: @Homam: Right, I want to know which *tab* the point lies within (the tab itself, as opposed to the larger page it is attached to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
TabPage GetPageByPoint(TabControl tabControl, Point point)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
    {
        TabPage page = tabControl.TabPages[i];
        if (tabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(point))
            return page;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I did try this, with no luck! Man, I think the problem is that I'm working with a point on the *screen*, not in relation to the tab control's client area. Maybe I can do the translation really quick...

Comment: You've mentioned that you're using [MouseUp] event, I've tried it, just pass [e.Location] to the method.

Comment: Aha! Just needed to add a little `TabControl.PointToClient` magic to translate the screen coordinates to a `Point` relative to the tab control's position. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said `MouseUp` (though I was using that originally); I ended up needing to deal with this on `DragDrop`, which supplies screen coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the overload of GetChildAtPoint with GetChildAtPointSkip - [this Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115303/tabcontrol-getchildatpoint-always-returns-top-tabpage) suggests it could work.

Comment: Definitely a useful overload to know about, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it here. The available flags for the `GetChildAtPointSkip` enum are `Invisible`, `Disabled`, and `Transparent`; but in fact, I don't actually want to "skip" *any* pages. I just want the actual tab at the given point. I think the MS rep who claimed the bug was fixed by this overload on Connect was either mistaken, or else referring to a slightly different bug.